# Install and configure script language bar on IDA from IDC to Python

Tags: idapython, ida-plugin

I'm new in the field of reverse engineering to detect malicious code in ELF file. 
I installed IDA on Ubuntu (https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml) then follow guide at https://github.com/idapython/src/wiki/Installation-Instructions

But it doesn't work (not show Script language Python to change from IDC)

How do I configure IDA on Ubuntu with plugin IDApython?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KGTr1KBDo6l1cmqGQhkx5hxQGuKK20Bs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

The free version of IDA doesn't support the IDAPython scripting engine. You'll have to get a commercial license.

The instructions you're trying to follow may also be a little outdated.

Comment: Thank u for replying, Nirlzr. What about using https://github.com/radare/radare2  to replace IDA pro? please

Comment: As @Biswapriyo said usage of IDA's demo for non-commercial purposes is totally fine, although most features will be missing. r2 is totally free and a decent disassembler so you should definitely consider it for free use.